# Animated ASCII art flickering in c

Tags: c, windows, ascii, ascii-art

I'm making an ASCII art game in c (windows), but for some reason when i play it is all flickering at apparently random intervals, and for most of the time i can't see anything. can anyone explain why or how to solve it?

this is my code:

```
const int WIDTH = 20, HEIGTH = 5;
const int AREA = (WIDTH) * HEIGTH;
const int gl = HEIGTH - 2; //Ground level
const float delta = 0.1f; //Frame rate
char scr[AREA]; //String for displaying stuff

char input;
int posx = 10, posy = gl - 1; //Player position
int vel = 0; //player velocity

while(1)
{
   //TODO: player input

    for(i = 0; i < AREA; i++) //Rendering part
    {
        if(i % WIDTH == 0 && i != 0)
        {
            scr[i] = '\n';
            continue;
        }

        if(floor(i / WIDTH) >= gl) //i is on ground
        {
            scr[i] = '.';
            continue;
        }


        scr[i] = ' ';
    }
    
    //Set player position
    scr[posy * WIDTH + posx + 1] = '@';
    scr[(posy + 1) * WIDTH + posx + 1] = '@';


    system("cls");// Clear terminal
    printf(scr);// Print screen
    usleep(delta * 1000);//Sleep
}
```

output:

```
          @
..........@........
...................►↓@
```

It works, but it flickers...

Comment: If you want other people to be able to reproduce your problem, you may want to consider providing a [mre], which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives.

Comment: _I'm guessing user will be able to write his name (or some other stuff) to the `scr`_, so please **don't `printf(scr);`**, it's a bad practice since it's not secure. User can leak addresses or even write to memory where he shouldn't with `"%n"`. I'd use `puts` or if you insist `printf_s`...

Comment: Instead of using `system("cls");`, you may want to consider using the [Console Functions API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) or [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences). Note that the latter requires an up-to-date Windows 10 or 11, it does not work with Windows 7.

Comment: Or another option would be a terminal capabilities library; on Windows there's pdcurses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible reason for your problem is that there may be output waiting in the output buffer when you call your sleep function `usleep`. In that case, you should always flush all output before sleeping, by calling the function `fflush( stdout );`.

Also, using `system("cls");` is highly inefficient. It is generally better to use the [Console Functions API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions), or, if you are targetting platforms with Windows 10 or later, you can also use [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) instead.

If you decide to use the Console Functions API, then the main functions that you will be needing in order to replace `system("cls");` are [`GetStdHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle) to obtain the output handle, and [`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition). That way, you won't have to clear the whole screen, but will only have to overwrite the parts of the screen that are changing. I also recommend that you replace `printf` with [`WriteConsole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole), otherwise you may run into buffering issues.

If this does not solve your flickering problem, then there also is the possibility of using [double-buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics). Both the [Console Functions API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) and [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) support this.

When using the Console Functions API, you can use the function [`CreateConsoleScreenBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/createconsolescreenbuffer) to create a new buffer to write to, without it being displayed immediately. This will allow you to first finish building the next screen, without any flickering occuring while doing so (because it is not being displayed yet). Once you have finished building the next screen, you can display it using the function [`SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleactivescreenbuffer).

Console Virtual Terminal Sequences offer similar functionality by supporting an [alternate screen buffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#alternate-screen-buffer).